# How to approach need for virtual page on my WP site?

Tags: pages, url-rewriting

I have a WP site and need to make all URLs like **/fruits/apple/** and **/fruits/banana/** lead to the same dynamic page e.g. rewritten as such: **/fruit-template?id=apple**

At the moment I have created the page /fruit-template using a custom template that handles the query string "id". I have tried WP URL rewriting to accomplish my goal, but **/fruits/apple/** always lead to 404.

Am I missing something? Is there another better approach to this need of a virtual page? Or can you suggest a proper rewrite rule that works?

Comment: It seems that you've forgotten flush rewrite cache. In the WordPress administration dashboard on the left-hand side, click “Settings” and then “Permalinks”. Scroll down to the bottom of the page after all of the existing options and click “Save Changes”. Or use flush_rewrite_rules to do it automatically

Comment: show us what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I've tried so far (and a number of experimental variations)

```
add_rewrite_rule('reviews/([^/]+)/?', 'review-template','top');
```

I have done flush_rewrite_rules multiple times and verified the changes in .htaccess.

Comment: Take a look at the function https://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule
Your second parameter should be rewrite url as `'index.php?page_id=$matches[1]'`. Not template name

Comment: Thank you, this seemed to solve my problem! URL is now properly rewritten.